# How to write a syncronous task that suspends on each iteration to allow the thread to continue until the thread is idle again

Tags: c#, task

I'm not sure what I want is possible.

I am writing a plugin for a host application it offers me object I wish to process the constraint is that I must process these object on the host main application thread only. If I touch them in another thread the Host dies.

I have written a mock scenario that demonstrates The situation and indicates via the comments what I would like to do.  Basically I get a bunch of objects to process.  I would like to make a Task (I think) which can iterate these objects processing them one at a time While the Host is Idle, but on each iteration pass back control to the thread so that the host may update it's idle status (via events) if the host says it's busy then I wish to keep my Processing Task suspended until the Host returns to the idle state.

I imagined it to be something like the following code. But I do not know how to attack this problem, I am not even sure if it is possible with `Task/Async` principals.

```
public class MockHost
{
    public event EventHandler Idle;
    public event EventHandler Busy;
    public event EventHandler<ModifiedObjectsEventArgs> IHaveModifiedObjectsHereYouGo;
}
public class ModifiedObjectsEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public object[] ModifiedObjects;
}
public class TestClass
{
    MockHost _host = new MockHost();
    ObjectProcessor _processor = new ObjectProcessor();


    public TestClass()
    {
        _host.Idle += _host_Idle;
        _host.Busy += _host_Busy;
        _host.IHaveModifiedObjectsHereYouGo += _host_IHaveModifiedObjectsHereYouGo;
    }

    private async void _host_IHaveModifiedObjectsHereYouGo(object sender, ModifiedObjectsEventArgs e)
    {
         await _processor.ProcessObjectsAsync(e.ModifiedObjects);
    }

    private void _host_Busy(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _processor.SetHostBusyState(true);
    }

    private void _host_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _processor.SetHostBusyState(false);
    }
}

public class ObjectProcessor
{
    bool _hostIsBusy = false;
    public void SetHostBusyState(bool isBusy)
    {
        _hostIsBusy = isBusy;
        if(!_hostIsBusy)
        {
            // Continue processing.
        }
    }
    public async Task ProcessObjectsAsync(Object[] objects)
    {
        foreach(object obj in objects)
        {
            if (_hostIsBusy)
            {
                // suspend this task somehow
            }
            else
            {
                ProcessObject(obj);
            }
            // suspend the task somehow to let the host events update busy status if they need to.
        }
    }

    private void ProcessObject(object obj)
    {
        // Long running process.
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than doing long running non-UI work in the UI thread, and trying to stop it for a while and let the UI events be processed *just don't do non-UI work in the UI thread* and do your non-UI work in a non-UI thread.

Comment: I have no choice it's enforced by the Host which I have no control over.  I can only interact with it's object on the host application thread.

Comment: If you want to temporarily give control back to the host, you can use `await Task.Yield();` (assuming the host has set a synchronization context)

Comment: @KevinGosse thanks I am looking into Task.Yield() now.  you know of any good examples on how to use it?

Comment: @John just put `await Task.Yield();` wherever you've commented "suspend the task somehow"

Comment: @KevinGosse Thanks that works a treat.  If you care to make it as an answer I will mark it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can yield control back to the host at any time by using:

```
await Task.Yield();
```

This assumes that the host has set a synchronization context.

What it does is ending the current task, and posting the continuation back to the synchronization context. This way, the host can get back the thread, run whatever code it needs, then give the control back to your continuation.